# How do I allow multiple connections to Upload and Downlod to and from a FTP server at the same time or make the connections synchronously in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a Discord Bot using nodejs which makes connections to a server for ftp transfers. However, when multiple users run the same command to download / upload files, I'm receiving the error:

> Error downloading file: User launched a task while another one is still running. Forgot to use
> 'await' or '.then()'?

Here is my code:

```js
async function ftpDownload(message) {
    console.log("Downloading file. . .");
    //ftpClient.ftp.verbose = true;
    ftpClient.ftp.ipFamily = 4;
    try {
        await ftpClient.access({
            host: ftpLocation,
            port: ftpPort,
            user: ftpusername,
            password: ftppassword
        });
        await ftpClient.downloadTo(steamID + ".json", serverSelection + steamID + ".json");

    } catch(err){
        console.error("Error downloading file: " + err.message);
        return message.reply('something went wrong.');
    }
    ftpClient.close();
    await editJson(message, option);
}
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```js
await ftpDownload(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. It seems I initiated one instance of the ftp client, so one user calling the same instance while it's already running resulted in my issue.  Simple resolution was to initiate the ftp client on each call of the download / upload functions.